# Python and Windows Named Pipes

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, named-pipes

What is the proper way of communicating with named pipes on Windows from Python? I've googled it, and can't find any packages that wrap this communication.

There are:

- some descriptions of how to do it with pywin32 (I could not find how to connect to an existing pipe with it, though).
- This package: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyWPipe/ (had no luck with it either)
- A piece of code here, that I haven't yet tested: https://jonathonreinhart.com/posts/blog/2012/12/13/named-pipes-between-c-and-python/

I need just to connect to an existing named pipe and read/write to it. I previously had only tried communication with serial port (using pySerial), and I'm surprised how little info I could find on named pipes in comparison to it. There's usually tons of guides for any purpose for Python.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: You should be able to use `f = open(r'\\.\PIPE\<pipe name>', 'rb+', buffering=0)`, and then call `f.read(nbytes)` and `f.write(string)`.

Comment: @eryksun your recommendation as along the lines with the third solution from my list, except that it's 'r+b', and you need to write bytes to file, not string. I myself was hoping that it is the right way to go, and indeed managed to establish communication with a named pipe this way. My previous mistake with it was that I sent ascii control codes the wrong way.

Comment: "rb+" and "r+b" are the same. Also, your question is tagged for Python 2 and makes no mention of Python 3, so naturally I assumed you were using Python 2, in which `str` strings are byte strings. In Python 3 you need to write `bytes`.

Comment: Got it. I didn't tag it specifically for Python 2, just for Python.

Comment: True, the Python tag can go both ways, but I still expect Python 3 questions to be tagged "Python-3.x". Mentally I suppose it's because `python` on most platforms is still Python 2, and running Python 3 requires `python3`.

Answer (score 62):

In order to connect to an existing named pipe you can utilize the `CreateFile` API provided through the `pywin32` package. Since it took me a while to put a working base together here is an example client/server which works fine for me (python 3.6.5, pywin32 223 on Windows 10 Pro x64):

```
import time
import sys
import win32pipe, win32file, pywintypes


def pipe_server():
    print("pipe server")
    count = 0
    pipe = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(
        r'\\.\pipe\Foo',
        win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
        win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_WAIT,
        1, 65536, 65536,
        0,
        None)
    try:
        print("waiting for client")
        win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, None)
        print("got client")

        while count < 10:
            print(f"writing message {count}")
            # convert to bytes
            some_data = str.encode(f"{count}")
            win32file.WriteFile(pipe, some_data)
            time.sleep(1)
            count += 1

        print("finished now")
    finally:
        win32file.CloseHandle(pipe)


def pipe_client():
    print("pipe client")
    quit = False

    while not quit:
        try:
            handle = win32file.CreateFile(
                r'\\.\pipe\Foo',
                win32file.GENERIC_READ | win32file.GENERIC_WRITE,
                0,
                None,
                win32file.OPEN_EXISTING,
                0,
                None
            )
            res = win32pipe.SetNamedPipeHandleState(handle, win32pipe.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE, None, None)
            if res == 0:
                print(f"SetNamedPipeHandleState return code: {res}")
            while True:
                resp = win32file.ReadFile(handle, 64*1024)
                print(f"message: {resp}")
        except pywintypes.error as e:
            if e.args[0] == 2:
                print("no pipe, trying again in a sec")
                time.sleep(1)
            elif e.args[0] == 109:
                print("broken pipe, bye bye")
                quit = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print("need s or c as argument")
    elif sys.argv[1] == "s":
        pipe_server()
    elif sys.argv[1] == "c":
        pipe_client()
    else:
        print(f"no can do: {sys.argv[1]}")
```

Example output client

```
> python pipe_test.py c
pipe client
no pipe, trying again in a sec
no pipe, trying again in a sec
no pipe, trying again in a sec
message: (0, b'0')
message: (0, b'1')
message: (0, b'2')
message: (0, b'3')
message: (0, b'4')
message: (0, b'5')
message: (0, b'6')
message: (0, b'7')
message: (0, b'8')
message: (0, b'9')
broken pipe, bye bye
```

Example output server

```
> python pipe_test.py s
pipe server
waiting for client
got client
writing message 0
writing message 1
writing message 2
writing message 3
writing message 4
writing message 5
writing message 6
writing message 7
writing message 8
writing message 9
finished now
```

Obviously you'd need some error checking around the various calls but that should work.

Additional side note: A colleague of mine ran into trouble with the pipe being closed the moment the client tried to perform I/O on it (exception claiming that "all pipe instances are busy"). It turned out that he was using `os.path.exists` in the client code to test whether the named pipe already existed before running `CreateFile` on it. This somehow breaks the pipe. So using the approach above (`CreateFile` wrapped in a try-except) is the safe way of trying to connect to a pipe until it has been created by the server end.

Comment: great! this is only pipe example i could find running on windows with python 3+

Comment: Don't you have to call some `CloseHandle()` on files created with `win32file.CreateFile()`? Is there a way to do this with `with`?

Comment: @SergeRogatch Yeah, you should probably put the same `finally` clause into the client as it is already present for the server.

Comment: Worked like charm on Win8.1 and `Py3.7.6`, after `pip install pywin32`.

Answer (score 6):

I have success with something like the following fragment. This code is derived from [CaptureSetup/Pipes — Python on Windows](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes#Way_3:_Python_on_Windows) — The Wireshark Wiki. It requires `win32pipe` and `win32file` from the [`pywin32`](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) package.

```
# pipename should be of the form \\.\pipe\mypipename
pipe = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(
        pipename,
        win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,
        win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_WAIT,
        1, 65536, 65536,
        300,
        None)
try:
    win32pipe.ConnectNamedPipe(pipe, None)

    while True:
        some_data = b'12345...'
        win32file.WriteFile(pipe, some_data)
        ...
finally:
    win32file.CloseHandle(pipe)
```

I don't know if it's 100% correct in the way it closes the pipe.

You referred to [The Perils and Triumphs of Being a Geek: Named Pipes between C# and Python](http://jonathonreinhart.blogspot.com.au/2012/12/named-pipes-between-c-and-python.html)—Jonathon Reinhart. I tried it, but it wasn't able to create the named pipe. I wonder if that code only works to open a named pipe that has already been created by another process.

Comment: A bit late but re: C# and Python.  C# code is the server,  python code is the client.  The server has to be running and waiting for the client before the client can start.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for using pipes in Audacity v3.4.2 on Windows.

Eventually, I created a script that tests Audacity's pipe for both Windows and macOS (I haven't tested on Linux).

```py
""""
Source - https://github.com/unfor19/audacity-scripting

Instructions:
1. Start Audacity
2. Enable mod-script-pipe - https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting.html
3. Restart Audacity
4. (Windows) Install pywin32 - `pip install pywin32`
4. (Windows) Download "pipelist" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pipelist
5. (Windows) Run "pipelist" to make sure Audacity's pipes are available - "FromSrvPipe" and "ToSrvPipe"
6. Run this script to send a command to Audacity and get the response

Usage:
   python audacity_pipetest.py
"""

import time
import sys
import os

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    import win32pipe
    import win32file
else:
    # No need to import anything for macOS or Linux
    pass


def send_command(TOFILE, EOL, command):
    """Send a single command."""
    time.sleep(0.5)
    full_command = command + EOL
    print(f"Send: >>> '{full_command}'")
    TOFILE.write(full_command)
    print("TOFILE Written")
    TOFILE.flush()
    print("TOFILE Flushed")


def get_response(FROMFILE):
    """Return the command response."""
    result = ''
    line = ''
    while True:
        result += line
        line = FROMFILE.readline()
        if line == '\n' and len(result) > 0:
            break
    print(f"Result: {result}")
    return result


def main():
    # Initialize variables for Windows and macOS/Linux
    # Pipe names and EOL is set according to - https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting.html
    pipe_name_send = ''
    pipe_name_from = ''
    pipe_send = None  # For Windows only
    EOL = ''

    if sys.platform == 'win32':
        pipe_name_send = r'\\.\pipe\ToSrvPipe'
        pipe_name_from = r'\\.\pipe\FromSrvPipe'
        EOL = '\r\n\0'
        pipe_send = win32pipe.CreateNamedPipe(
            pipe_name_send,
            win32pipe.PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
            win32pipe.PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | win32pipe.PIPE_WAIT,
            1, 65536, 65536,
            0,
            None)
    else:
        # macOS or Linux
        pipe_name_send = '/tmp/audacity_script_pipe.to.' + str(os.getuid())
        pipe_name_from = '/tmp/audacity_script_pipe.from.' + str(os.getuid())
        EOL = '\n'
    print(f"Trying to access pipe {pipe_send}")
    try:
        # Set command to send to Audacity
        # According to - https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/scripting_reference.html
        CMD = f'GetInfo: Preferences'  # Sample command

        # Open file buffer in write according to the platform
        print(f"Accessing send pipe - '{pipe_name_send}' ...")
        with open(pipe_name_send, 'w') as fp:
            print("Accessed send pipe")
            # Send command to Audacity using the write pipe
            send_command(fp, EOL, CMD)

        print(f"Accessing from pipe - '{pipe_name_from}' ...")
        # Open file buffer in text mode - must set encoding as Windows uses cp1252 by default
        with open(pipe_name_from, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
            print("Accessed from pipe")
            # Get response from Audacity using the read pipe
            response = get_response(fp)
            print(f"Response:\n{response}")
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    finally:
        if sys.platform == 'win32':
            win32file.CloseHandle(pipe_send)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Source - https://github.com/unfor19/audacity-scripting/blob/feature/initial-test/scripts/audacity_pipetest.py

I tested it locally on Windows 11 Pro 22H2 and Python 3.9.13; I intend to make it work in GitHub Actions `windows-*` instances and will update here once it's done.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but if anybody is interested, I published the `namedpipe` package on PyPI to enable named pipes in both Posix and Windows. Here is a link to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-namedpipe).

It's API is modeled after built-in `open()` and `IO` classes. A quick usage sample:

```py
import subproces as sp
from namedpipe import NPopen

with NPopen('r+') as pipe: # bidirectional (duplex) binary pipe
    # - for an inbound pipe, specify the read access mode 'rb' or 'rt' 
    # - for an outbound pipe, specify the write access mode 'wb or 'wt'

    sp.run(['my_client', pipe.path])

    stream = pipe.wait() # Wait for the client to connect and create a stream

    b = stream.read(64)      # read 64 bytes from the client
    in_bytes = bytearray(128)
    nread = stream.readinto(in_bytes) # read 128 bytes of data from client
    b_rest = stream.readall() # read all bytes sent by the client, block
    stream.write(out_bytes) # send bytes in out_bytes to the client
```

Note: I wrote it a few year ago to work with the [`ffmpegio`](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio) but I haven't yet encountered a use-case myself ironically. So, I hope someone can make a good use of it.