# Named Pipes in Windows: Python server, C# Client

Tags: python-3.x, windows, server, named-pipes

I have read this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57056598/named-pipes-ipc-python-server-c-sharp-client) on named pipes, but it is for Unix only. Any idea on how can one create named pipes in Windows (without using the [PyWin32 extensions](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html))? Accessing a pipe (as client from Python) in Windows is as easy as doing "open", but I was not able to find such clean/simple way of creating it in Python.

Best regards,
Hugo

Comment: What's wrong with using PyWin32?

Comment: I am not saying something is wrong with PyWin32, I just want to know if there is a "standard" way without using additional external modules. If there is no such way, then I am fine with that answer.

Comment: When dealing with Windows internals like this, PyWin32 is generally (not always, but generally) the best way to go. Trying to roll your own using the std lib would likely be extremely painful...