# Wait for Named Pipe to be read before Disconnecting

Tags: python, c++, pipe

I have a program written in Python that I need to contact from a C++ Program. I'm creating the Pipe Server on the C++ program with the client being in Python. I can't wrap my head around how to properly read/write between the 2 programs as each time I try a different behavior occurs. Note that I want the pipe to remain open for multiple reads/writes into the future.

Server (C++)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define FGPIPE TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\FGChroma")

int main()
{

    HANDLE hPipe;
    DWORD dwWritten;
    DWORD MAX_BUF_SIZE = 8;

    hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(FGPIPE,
                            PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,
                            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
                            2,
                            MAX_BUF_SIZE*16,
                            0,
                            NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
                            NULL
                            );

    cout<<"Pipe? "<<hPipe<<endl;

    cout<<"Awaiting Connection"<<endl;
    cout<<ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL)<<endl;
    cout<<"Connected"<<endl;
    WriteFile(hPipe, "MSG1\n", 5, &dwWritten, NULL);
    WriteFile(hPipe, "MSG2\n", 5, &dwWritten, NULL);
    FlushFileBuffers(hPipe);
    ///Need to Wait for read here
    cout<<"Disconnecting"<<endl;
    DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);

}
```

Client (Python)

```
f = open(r"\\.\\pipe\\FGChroma", 'r', 0)
while True:
    value = f.read()
    print(value)
```

When I attempt to do the `f.read()` in Python, I get an error OSError 22 Invalid Argument, which is fair since I've disconnected the pipe. However if I don't disconnect the pipe then the Python code never finishes reading and keeps waiting until the pipe is closed or disconnected. I feel like the solution is simple and I'm just missing something tiny that's going over my head. I read the Documentation for named pipes and the Win APIs, I also tried win32py and other alternatives and I face the same issue; I don't understand how to keep a connection alive between the 2 instances and allow for reading without having to disconnect, or to wait for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with Python `f.read()` and Windows pipes. Maybe I missed something but it looks like there is no EOF when you read a pipe like you do, and python `read()` will read past the end and error, even though it read everything correctly before.

To work around this, you can use a buffered pipe (`open(r"pipe", 'r')`) and then either read characters one by one (`f.read(1)`) until you have an error, or use `os.read(f.fileno(), 1024)`, which is lower level and works in this case.

Comment: Disclaimer: I didn't test with unbuffered pipe because it's apparently unsupported in python 3.

Comment: Absolutely marvelous answer. I suspected it's the EOF issue (hence why people where using win32py.ReadFile), but your solution to use f.read(1) worked perfectly! I replace 1 with my buffer size and now everything is stable.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look here [Python and Windows Named Pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542644/python-and-windows-named-pipes)

thought on windows open a file by more than one program is not like on unix. If you can't avoid it use win32pipe but that makes your code not plattform indipendent

Answer (score 0):

Based on [ElderBug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4340578/elderbug)'s answer above, here's a working solution that doesn't use buffers, but instead uses an end of line terminator. You may need to adjust your code accordingly.

```
def read_line(file_handle):
    EOF = False
    data = ""
    while True:
        try:
            c = file_handle.read(1).decode("utf-8")
        except OSError: # EOF
            EOF = True
            break
        if c == '\n':
            break
        if not c:
            EOF = True
            break
        data += c
    return data, EOF

print("Connecting to Pipe")
while True:
    try:
        f = open(r"\\.\\pipe\\FGChroma", 'rb', 0)
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        continue

print("Connected")

print("Reading Data")

while True:
    data, EOF = read_line(f)
    if EOF: break
    print(data)
```

You may need to switch read mode from `'rb'` to `'r'` as well. Use `b` only for Binary mode, but then you'll have to enable buffering by setting buffer mode to `1` from `0`.