# equivalent to 'os.mkfifo()' in python

Tags: python, windows, named-pipes, mkfifo

I have a script that I need to translate from unix to windows. The script uses the 'os.mkfifo()' method to create a named pipe. This function is not available under windows. I have found the 'os.pipe()' method, but it doesn't allow to specify a name. The win32pipe api should do the right thing, but all examples I have found seem needlessly complicated.
Is there anything that serves as a good alternative to the 'mkfifo' method under windows?

edit:
To clarify the use case. I am creating two pipes in the script.

```
os.mkfifo('/path/to/sendpipe')
os.mkfifo('/path/to/receivepipe')
```

Another java script accesses these pipes to communicate, which is why I need an explicit file name rather than a pipe ID (which I would get from 'os.pipe()').

Comment: It might help if you provided a simple example that showed how you are currently using `os.mkfifo`.

Comment: Do you have the option of not using named pipes? I had some code that used Unix sockets (which like named pipes are exposed on the filesystem), and it ran into issues due to security issues on a particular container platform, so I just rewrote it to use local TCP sockets instead.

Comment: I'm currently getting around the problem by just using text files. It works but it's not ideal

Comment: @panjaap Did you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48542644/984421)?