# Sharing real time data between a VB.net application and a python script

Tags: python, vb.net

I have two scripts in my Visual Studio 2019 solution.
One in visual basic, and one in python.

They run independently, but I need to share realtime data.

I tried to reference the python project in the vb form, but it doesn't allow me to do that (I suppose because python is not compiled).

So I added a json file, but once the python script starts writing the vb form cannot read it anymore.

Is there a proper way to send data in my case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python and Windows Named Pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48542644/python-and-windows-named-pipes)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.